# video replaying issues with video.js on google chrome

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

I have problem of replaying a video for the first time on Google Chrome if it is not cached. I'm using VideoJS which contains the video URL as something like "http://somedaim.com/?querystring=value". I noticed this works for the URL something like "http://somedomain.com/video.mp4". Is this an issue of videoJS and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @Andrew. But what what we can do is at "ended" event if we set the source again it works! :)

`myPlayer.on("ended", function () {
    this.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: URL });
});`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is general webpage linking not videojs. The physical movie couldn't be located at http://somedaim.com/?querystring=value

Most likely the server or back end code redirect it to the mp4 path without you knowing (videojs wouldn't know this is happening and nor should it). Theres no way around it, you need the physical path to the mp4 file.